# Holiday on Cruise Ship

Tags: passports

My friend and I are flying to Florida and next day boarding a Cruise Ship for onward cruise to four islands and then onwards back to the UK.   Why do we have to upload our passports.  Is this necessary.   It is all so complicated.  I dont think we will be able to get the forms completed

How do you UPLOAD a passport

Comment: Which company and it might help if you add which city you sail from?

Comment: Upload your passports to where?

Comment: Here's a [guide to uploading passports](https://www.brunel.ac.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/115892/Passport-Guide-2011.pdf). It's for a university, not a cruise, but the general idea is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Not really sure what your question is asking, but if it is around just the passport uploading bit then that is easy - the company will tell you to upload a scan of particular pages from your passport (often the personal identification and relevant visa pages) - but some companies just want you to tell them the key details.

They will also tell you exactly how to do that (some have a web application, some want the details emailed)

As to why - that's so they know who is travelling, and can validate passenger details.